# On the product of a stochastic integral and a random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $Y$ be a random variable that lives on the same space as the stochastic integral $\int\limits_a^b X_t dZ_t$ for stochastic processes $X$ and $Z$. I would like sufficient conditions such that the equality $$Y \int\limits_a^b X_tdZ_t = \int\limits_a^b YX_tdZ_t$$ is true. I know that if $Z$ is a right continuous $L^2$ martingale and $Y$ is bounded and measurable wrt to the $\sigma$-field at time $a$, then this equality holds true.

Can these assumptions be relaxed, in particular such that $Y$ needn't be bounded? I had the idea of identifying $Y$ with the process $(Y)_t$ and using Ito's product rule (see [Product Rule for Ito Processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997889/product-rule-for-ito-processes)) to get
$$d(X_tY_t) = Y_tdX_t+X_tdY_t+d[X_t,Y_t]$$
where the last two terms are equal to $0$ as $Y$ is pathwise constant. Then using something like $\int Y d(\int XdZ) = \int YXdZ$ should give me the desired equality without using boundedness.

Does this proof work?

Comment: In general one cannot bring the random variable $Y$ inside the stochastic integral. I am not aware of sufficient conditions (besides independence). What I do know is that if instead of using the dot product between $Y$ and the stochastic integral you consider the Wick product "$\diamond$" then you can bring $Y$ inside. (notice that if $Y$ is not $\mathcal F_a$ measurable you will end up with a Skorohod integral)

Comment: You can find a nice discussion about this in "Gaussian Hilbert spaces" by Svante Janson (on the chapter about stochastic integration) and on  "Stochastic partial differential equations" by Holden et al.

Comment: Regarding  your question about the boundedness, I think this assumption is made in order to have that the integrand $YX_t$ satisfies the conditions needed to be Itô/Skorohod integrable. So I think you could come up with weaker conditions that still ensure the latter holds